# How can I make SVG text letters fade out from right to left?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG text file with two words in it, and I'm trying to make a scroll animation in which all of the letters with the `.letter` class fade out whilst having the first letter of each word remain. Is there a way in which I can have the opacity effect sweep across the letters from the right hand side towards the left so they don't all fade out at the same time? Is there a CSS solution to this problem (like a translucent gradient) that doesn't involve animating each letter individually?

https://jsfiddle.net/wvps3rc6/1/

**html**

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 136.6 17.65"><path class="h" d="M15.89,16.27H6.3V24H3.7V6.67H6.3V14h9.59V6.67h2.6V24h-2.6Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M27.8,11.14c3.77,0,6.11,2.94,6.11,6.79v.57H24a4.11,4.11,0,0,0,4.26,3.9A5.33,5.33,0,0,0,32,20.92l1.09,1.54a7,7,0,0,1-5,1.87,6.28,6.28,0,0,1-6.5-6.61A6.32,6.32,0,0,1,27.8,11.14ZM24,16.81h7.67a3.71,3.71,0,0,0-3.82-3.74A3.85,3.85,0,0,0,24,16.81Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M36.85,6.67h2.34V24H36.85Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M42.91,6.67h2.34V24H42.91Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M48.18,17.72a6.24,6.24,0,0,1,6.35-6.58c3.92,0,6.34,3,6.34,6.58s-2.42,6.61-6.34,6.61S48.18,21.36,48.18,17.72Zm10.25,0c0-2.36-1.38-4.5-3.9-4.5s-3.9,2.14-3.9,4.5,1.4,4.53,3.9,4.53S58.43,20.12,58.43,17.72Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="w" d="M80.27,10.62,76.68,24H73.9l-5-17.34h2.91l3.59,13.91,3.8-13.91h2.1l3.78,13.91L88.69,6.67h2.92L86.67,24H83.88Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M91.94,17.72a6.24,6.24,0,0,1,6.35-6.58c3.92,0,6.34,3,6.34,6.58s-2.42,6.61-6.34,6.61S91.94,21.36,91.94,17.72Zm10.25,0c0-2.36-1.38-4.5-3.9-4.5s-3.9,2.14-3.9,4.5,1.4,4.53,3.9,4.53S102.19,20.12,102.19,17.72Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M107.59,11.46h2.34v1.92A5.35,5.35,0,0,1,114,11.17v2.37a3.73,3.73,0,0,0-.8-.08,4.45,4.45,0,0,0-3.31,1.82V24h-2.34Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M116.38,6.67h2.34V24h-2.34Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="letter" d="M131.38,22.22a5.17,5.17,0,0,1-4.1,2.11c-3.28,0-5.62-2.47-5.62-6.58s2.34-6.61,5.62-6.61a5.11,5.11,0,0,1,4.1,2.14V6.67h2.34V24h-2.34Zm0-7.15a4.35,4.35,0,0,0-3.48-1.85c-2.34,0-3.8,1.9-3.8,4.53s1.46,4.5,3.8,4.5a4.32,4.32,0,0,0,3.48-1.82Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/><path class="full-stop" d="M138.66,21.05a1.64,1.64,0,0,1,1.64,1.61,1.66,1.66,0,0,1-1.64,1.64,1.64,1.64,0,0,1-1.61-1.64A1.62,1.62,0,0,1,138.66,21.05Z" transform="translate(-3.7 -6.67)"/></svg>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.text-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin:10px;
  width: 400px;
}

svg#Layer-1 {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

path.letter {
  fill: #000000;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

body.logo-shrink path.letter {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {

        $('body').addClass('logo-shrink');

    } else {

        $('body').removeClass('logo-shrink');

    }
    
});
```